# Running virtual desktops (like Spaces on Mac OS) on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtual-desktop

I make much use of Ctrl-arrows to new virtual desktops on my MacBook to get more real estate, organize like-applications and windows, and help focus on a task at a time.

How can I get the same or similar feature to work in Windows 7?

The Ctrl-arrows behavior on Mac that I'm talking about include stuff like:

- Keyboard shortcuts to slide to a new desktop
- Sliding a window/app to an edge activates/moves the app to that virtual desktop
- Zoom-out view allows you to see position and location of all windows on all desktops
- Taskbar icon/view allows for easy two-click jump to any desktop
- Remembers which apps open in which virtual desktop, on re-launch moves you to that desktop for app launch

(And, no, 'install Mac OS X' is not what I'm looking for.)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can use virtual desktops in Windows utilizing the Sysinternals tools. [Desktops](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/desktops) is the module you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

Check with your video card vendor.

Nvidia had a "virtual desktop" utility that worked like my KDE Workspaces functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 now does that through the "virtual desktop" features.

You can see the virtual desktops via holding [Windows]+[Tab], and add a virtual desktop via clicking on "Add desktop" from there.
Then, you can move from a virtual desktop to another with the [Windows]+[Control]+[Right or Left arrow].

One thing that prevents me from using it as I would on a Linux or a Mac is that, on a multi-monitor set-up, switching virtual desktops will switch the desktop on all the monitors at the same time.

Windows 7 being no longer supported by Microsoft, I would suppose that you have moved to Windows 10.

Comment: +1 and it's entirely frustrating and sort of makes the feature useless.

Comment: What linux desktop is providing those separate desktops on different monitors? I cant find one

Comment: @salcoin please tell me i need to know lol

Comment: I haven't used Linux in forever, but I know it's possible. Don't remember if it's out of the box, or if you need to tweak stuff first though